# Detecting selection change on a UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

Is there a way to detect when the user changes the range of the selected text in a textview (In a subclass of UITextView)?
I couldn't find any NSNotification. I tried observing keyvalues but the observer for selected range does not get called

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedRange" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"selectedRange"])
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

**I DO NOT want to use the delegate method of UITextView**

Comment: What is wrong with the delegate?

Comment: Do you want a notification when the text changes?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique I am writing a Custom UITextView, but using the delegate inside the UITextView itself, it no longer can be used else where (ex: in the UIViewController)

Comment: Do you want a notification when the text changes?

Comment: I am not looking for text change, I'm looking for SELECTION change

Comment: [self addObserver:self... ] ??? Is this in a subclass of UITextView? If not, that certainly won't work. If it is, why don't you just override the -setSelectedRange method? Don't use KVO unless normal method overrides and other reasonable solutions simply won't work. And NEVER use KVO on self. Implement your accessor with the necessary logic.

Comment: @BoredAstronaut Yes it's in the subclass of the TextView, in awakeFromNib, It gets called when the text changes, or the attributes string changes, but not when the selection changes. setSelectedRange doesn't get called for some reasons, I tried that already

Comment: @BoredAstronaut Solved, your answer gave me a hint: setSelectedTextRange is the correct method not setSelectedRange. Leave the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`UITextView` adopts the `UITextInput` protocol. That protocol includes a required `selectedTextRange` read/write property. That is the property you want to respond to changes of.

While you could observe that property, the simplest approach is to override the `-setSelectedTextRange:` method in your subclass and perform whatever additional behaviours you need in there. (You may or may not want to confirm that the range is actually changing, depending on your particular design.)

Comment: Doesn't seem to trigger when the selection changes due to typing, though.

Answer (score 1):

UITextView's delegate () conforms to this since iOS2

```
-(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    //read textView.selectedRange
}
```

I also personally like to manually trigger it when dismissing a keyboard since that also is a selection change in my opinion but won't trigger the delegate callback on its own (an overlooking on Apple's part in my humble opinion)

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
    [self textViewDidChangeSelection:textView];
}
```