# Detecting SELECTION change on a UITextView and/or UITextField without using the delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

I am writing a Custom UITextView, but using the delegate inside the UITextView itself, it no longer can be used else where (ex: in the UIViewController).

So, is there a way to detect when the user changes the range of the selected text in a textview or textfield because I need the caret position. I couldn't find any `NSNotification` to do something like this :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(selectionDidChange:) 
      name: ?? // someNotification
       object:textView];
```

Then do something with the selector

```
-(void)selectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
     //do something
}
```

I got a hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17900582/3336675), but don't know how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to made our own protocol for your custom TextField. In your custom textfield, you implement the UItextfieldDelegate protocols and you made your own to prevent the UIVIewController.

in your .h

```
@protocol YourCustomTextFieldDelegate <NSObject>

  - (void) userDidChangeRange:(NSRange*) currentRange;

@end
@interface YourCustomTextField : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate> {
  UITextField *_customTextField;
} 

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<YourCustomTextFieldDelegate> delegate
```

in your .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 //Create your customTextField and add it to the view
 _customTextField.delegate = self;

 }

#pragma mark - UItextField Delegate

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:    (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  [self.delegate userDidChangeRange:range]; 
  return YES;
}
```

Edit :With notification post
in your .h

```
  interface YourCustomTextField : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UITextField *_customTextField;
  }
```

in your .m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   //Create your customTextField and add it to the view
   _customTextField.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - UItextField Delegate

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:       (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   [[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"YourNotificationName" object:self userInfo:@{@"range": range, @"textFieldTag" : @"[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.tag]}]; 
  return YES;
}
```

The user will listen to your notification with

```
 - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(rangeDiDChange) name:@"YourNotificationName" object:nil];
}
```

I suggest that in the notification you set the tag to recognise your textfield, if you have many custom textfield in your view controller, to recognise it.

Hope it will help.

Comment: The project is a library, so any modification in the viewController isn't an option and that's why I said "no delegate methods"!!

Comment: You can make @Optional func in your delegate method. Or use notification, you post a notification in shouldChangeCharactersInRange, and the user will or not listen to your notification. Many library use optional and custom options are using delegates.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please give me an example code which looks like my sample code(in the question)? Sorry for the inconvenience, but I am new to iOS and obj C.

Comment: I have edit the original answer, hope it will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

UITextViewDelegate has this

```
-(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    //textView.selectedRange
}
```

Important, dismissing keyboard (if you have a toolbar with done button for example) will not trigger the selection change method, even though selection has now changed (to 0) so I recommend also calling this method in the end editing method as well, while also manually setting the selected range to nil

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
    [self textViewDidChangeSelection:textView];
}
```